# Test existing column in query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have this script below:

```
---------Part 1--------
SELECT 
    COLUMN_NAME 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         SC.name as TABLE_SCHEMA,
         t.name as TABLE_NAME,
         ind.name as indexName,
         ind.type_desc AS type_Index,
         SUBSTRING((SELECT ', ' + AC.name
                    FROM DATA.sys.[tables] AS T
                    INNER JOIN DATA.sys.[indexes] I   ON T.[object_id] = I.[object_id]
                    INNER JOIN DATA.sys.[index_columns] IC ON I.[object_id] = IC.[object_id] AND I.[index_id] = IC.[index_id]
                    INNER JOIN DATA.sys.[all_columns] AC ON T.[object_id] = AC.[object_id] AND IC.[column_id] = AC.[column_id] 
                    WHERE Ind.[object_id] = I.[object_id] AND Ind.index_id = I.index_id AND IC.is_included_column = 0
                    ORDER BY IC.key_ordinal
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 8000) AS COLUMN_NAME
     FROM DATA.sys.indexes ind 
     INNER JOIN DATA.sys.index_columns ic ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and ind.index_id = ic.index_id 
     INNER JOIN DATA.sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id 
     INNER JOIN DATA.sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id
     INNER JOIN DATA.sys.schemas SC ON t.schema_id =  SC.schema_id
     WHERE SC.name ='SCHEMA1') AS SubQ
WHERE 
    COLUMN_NAME IN 
     -------Part 2-------
        (SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
         FROM DATA.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
         WHERE DATA_TYPE IN ('nchar', 'nvarchar')
           AND TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('SCHEMA1', 'SCHEMA2'))
```

When I run the part 1 or the part 2, I got the best the columns, and the two results are the same, but when I run all the script it does not dispaly any thing, and no errors.

Some help please ?
Thank you

Comment: Because those two queries are not returning the column name. In your first query you are return a comma delimited list that begins with a space. And the leading space is not ignored when looking at the column name in the second query. As such if you have  column named "MyColumn" you trying to find rows where " MyColumn" is in "MyColumn".

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange. How I can corrige it ?

Comment: Well...I don't know what you are trying to do. What is your intended output?

Comment: before the part 1, I used IF EXISTS to test if the COLUMN_NAME exist in the part 2, I drop all the indexes that contais this types of the columns

Comment: Another thing, the two queries are returned a columns, querie 1 returns 746 rows and queries 2 return 256 rows

Comment: I think you need to step back and figure out what you are trying to do here. The row counts in these two queries are going to be different. The first one is looking at indexes for 1 schema, the second is looking at column names in 2 schemas. Instead of trying to explain your code maybe you need to explain what you are trying to do. The code you have here needs a lot of work to get you where you are trying to go.